# Not sure why my code keeps printing 'wrong answer'

Tags: python, if-statement, inline

In my code below, when I input the correct answer, the 'wrong...guess again' keeps printing. This is within the first if statement. I dont know how to set up a conditional for it to print only when the answer is wrong. thanks for the help.

```
out_of_guesses = False
answer = 'dog'
max_guess = 3
guess = ''
guess_counter = 0

while guess != answer and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_counter < max_guess:
       guess = input('pick an animal')
       guess_counter += 1
       print ('wrong...guess again')

    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print ('you lose')
else:
    print('you win')
```

I typed up everything on the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the statement to print in the same if block as the input, meaning it runs with every input. You want to place the "wrong" logic outside of the input logic, or you can add a nested if statement to check what the user input. This code functions how you wish:

```
out_of_guesses = False
answer = 'dog'
max_guess = 3
guess = ''
guess_counter = 0

while guess != answer and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_counter < max_guess:
       guess = input('pick an animal')
       guess_counter += 1
    if guess != answer and guess_counter >= max_guess:
        print ('you lose')
        out_of_guesses = True
    elif guess != answer:
        print ('wrong...guess again')
    else:
        print("you win!")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer-- Now the issue is, when I run this code and guess wrong too many times, it says ' wrong answer guess again, as well as 'you lose'. I dont want it to run 'guess again' after the guesses are done.

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix this by checking if the user is out of guesses before telling them to guess again.

Comment: So now is the out_of_guesses variable even necessary? It looks to me that its not used within the second if block.

Comment: The out_of_guesses is what stops the while loop. If that variable wasn't present, then the loop would run forever. However, you could substitute it in the definition of the while loop with "guess_counter < max_guess" and then you could remove the out_of_guesses variable entirely.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Sam's answer, the condition for the while loop is only evaluated at the beginning of every iteration, not between each line. This means that the loop will not continue to ask for inputs once you've guessed correctly (the whole condition is now false), but it will finish the current iteration, printing "wrong," regardless of what the guess was

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue in your code. The problem lies in the placement of the "wrong...guess again" print statement within the first if block. This statement currently prints regardless of whether the guess is correct or incorrect. To fix this, move the "wrong...guess again" print statement inside the if block that checks for an incorrect guess. Here's the corrected code:

```py
out_of_guesses = False
answer = 'dog'
max_guess = 3
guess = ''
guess_counter = 0

while guess != answer and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_counter < max_guess:
       guess = input('pick an animal: ')
       guess_counter += 1
       if guess != answer:  # Move the print statement inside this block
           print('wrong...guess again')
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print('you lose')
else:
    print('you win')
```

This change ensures that "wrong...guess again" will only print when the guess is incorrect and within the maximum guess limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this greatly by using a *for / else* construct as follows:

```
answer = "dog"

for _ in range(3):
    if input("pick an animal: ") == answer:
        print("you win!")
        break
else:
    print("you lose")
```

Comment: Thank you for this response-- I still have yet to learn for loops and breaks but will keep this in mind for later.